# How to freeze ahk window spy in windows 8

Tags: window, autohotkey, freeze, spy

My Window Spy says "Shift-Alt-Tab to freeze display" but ShfitAltTab winminimizes all windows.
How can I freeze the Window Spy of autohotkey in Windows 8?

Comment: "Shift-Alt-Tab" is like "alt-tab" but in the other direction. To be honest I didn't even see the freeze feature working on Windows 7. Instead of freezing it you could make a screenshot and paste it in paint afterwards. It's a annoying solution though. What I'm doing is just writing my own "widows spy" scripts. You can pretty much build your own windowspy using the following commands: "MouseGetPos", "MouseGetPos", "WinGet", "WinGetTitle", "WinGettext", "WinGetPos" and "ControlGet". The cool thing whe writing your own windowspy is that you can even directly log the output into a file etc.